# If x,y,z are posititive real numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, factoring

If x,y,z are positive real numbers, and 
$\frac{x^{19}}{y^{19}}+\frac{y^{19}}{z^{19}}+\frac{z^{19}}{x^{19}}≤\frac{x^{19}}{z^{19}}+\frac{y^{19}}{x^{19}}+\frac{z^{19}}{y^{19}}$

How do you prove:

$\frac{x^{20}}{y^{20}}+\frac{y^{20}}{z^{20}}+\frac{z^{20}}{x^{20}}≤\frac{x^{20}}{z^{20}}+\frac{y^{20}}{x^{20}}+\frac{z^{20}}{y^{20}}$

I was able to prove it with a simpler case, however, I am assuming that the first power inequality is true. I don't know if that is correct, but it's just to show a method:

Assuming: $\frac{x^{}}{y^{}}+\frac{y^{}}{z^{}}+\frac{z^{}}{x^{}}≤\frac{x^{}}{z^{}}+\frac{y^{}}{x^{}}+\frac{z^{}}{y^{}}$

Prove: $\frac{x^{2}}{y^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{z^{2}}+\frac{z^{2}}{x^{2}}≤\frac{x^{2}}{z^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}+\frac{z^{2}}{y^{2}}$

In this case, you would multiply the first power inequality by itself, and you would get: $\frac{x^{2}}{y^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{z^{2}}+\frac{z^{2}}{x^{2}} + 2(\frac{x^{}}{z^{}}+\frac{y^{}}{x^{}}+\frac{z^{}}{y^{}})≤\frac{x^{2}}{z^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}+\frac{z^{2}}{y^{2}}+ 2(\frac{x^{}}{y^{}}+\frac{y^{}}{z^{}}+\frac{z^{}}{x^{}})$

This would be easy to prove. the first power inequalty is doubled and has flipped sides. Since the terms have flipped sides, in order to keep the new inequality true, $\frac{x^{2}}{y^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{z^{2}}+\frac{z^{2}}{x^{2}}≤\frac{x^{2}}{z^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{x^{2}}+\frac{z^{2}}{y^{2}}$
 must be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^{19}}{z^{19}}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^{19}}{y^{19}}$$ it's
$$(x^{19}-y^{19})(x^{19}-z^{19})(y^{19}-z^{19})\geq0$$ or
$$(x-y)(x-z)(y-z)\geq0.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Here's my proof, tell me if it makes sense: 
We can first bring the left side of the 20th power equation to the right side to get: 

$\left(\frac{x^{20}}{z^{20}}+\frac{y^{20}}{x^{20}}+\frac{z^{20}}{y^{20}}\right)-\left(\frac{x^{20}}{y^{20}}+\frac{y^{20}}{z^{20}}+\frac{z^{20}}{x^{20}}\right)≥0$

If we subtract the terms and combine like terms, we get:
$\frac{x^{40}y^{20}-x^{20}y^{40}+y^{40}z^{20}-y^{20}z^{40}+x^{20}z^{40}-x^{40}z^{20}}{x^{20}y^{20}z^{20}}≥0$ Since x,y,z are all positive, the denominator will have to be positive, so we can disregard it while proving the inequality.

Comment: Our new inequality is: $x^{40}y^{20}-x^{20}y^{40}+y^{40}z^{20}-y^{20}z^{40}+x^{20}z^{40}-x^{40}z^{20}≥0$

we can factor this to get: $\left(x^{20}-y^{20}\right)\left(x^{20}-z^{20}\right)\left(y^{20}-z^{20}\right)≥0$

We can do this strategy on the 19th power inequality to get: $\left(x^{19}-y^{19}\right)\left(x^{19}-z^{19}\right)\left(y^{19}-z^{19}\right)≥0$

Comment: We can now multiply this inequality by $\frac{\left(x^{20}-y^{20}\right)\left(x^{20}-z^{20}\right)\left(y^{20}-z^{20}\right)}{\left(x^{19}-y^{19}\right)\left(x^{19}-z^{19}\right)\left(y^{19}-z^{19}\right)}$ on both sides to get:
 $\left(x^{20}-y^{20}\right)\left(x^{20}-z^{20}\right)\left(y^{20}-z^{20}\right)≥0$

We have hence proven the original inequality.

Comment: @joeken Why the last fraction is positive?

Comment: I'm sorry, which fraction are you referring to?

Comment: Also, if you get some time, could you please check this inequality out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3371634/are-there-positive-integers-that-make-this-equation-true-2x2-2y11-46

Comment: @joeken Why does $\frac{(x^{20}-y^{20})(x^{20}-z^{20})(y^{20}-z^{20})}{(x^{19}-y^{19})(x^{19}-z^{19})(y^{19}-z^{19})}$? If it follows from my hint, so your reasoning is true.